# Best way to take Command Line Arguments in Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

In my Python script, I have a lot of command line arguments. Some of them are mandatory while others are optional. Some of the optional are mandatory for certain values of mandatory params as well. What is the best way to take in such a case of command line arguments. I am using `argparse.Argumentparser` for my purpose.

To clarify the use case, here is an example. Let's say I have 3 mandatory params: `mode, foo, bar` and 5 optional params: `op1, op2, op3, op4, op5`. Lets say, `mode` can have 3 values: `m1, m2, m3`. If `mode` is `m1`, `op1 and op2` are mandatory. If `mode` is `m2`, `op3` is mandatory and if `mode` is `m3`, `op4 and op5` are mandatory.

What is the best way to put it into code? What I'm doing now seems too exhaustive and just feels that there has to be better ways to do this.

### -> Current code

```
import argparse

# create and execute parser
my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Demo")
my_parser.add_argument("--mode", action="store", type=str, required=True)
my_parser.add_argument("--foo", action="store", type=str, required=True)
my_parser.add_argument("--bar", action="store", type=str, required=True)
my_parser.add_argument("--op1", action="store", type=str, required=False, default=None)
my_parser.add_argument("--op2", action="store", type=str, required=False, default=None)
my_parser.add_argument("--op3", action="store", type=str, required=False, default=None)
my_parser.add_argument("--op4", action="store", type=str, required=False, default=None)
my_parser.add_argument("--op5", action="store", type=str, required=False, default=None)
args = my_parser.parse_args()
try:
    if args.mode == "m1":
        op1 = args.op1.lower()
        op2 = args.op2.lower()
    if args.mode == "m2":
        op3 = args.op3.split(',')
    if args.mode == "m3":
        op4 = args.op4.lower()
        op5 = args.op5.lower()
except AttributeError:
    print("Wrong mode set for optional arguments")
    exit()
```

As you can see, even this example just "looks" aesthetically bad (esp `try` block parsing) and I have a lot many optional arguments to deal with in my case. Any help will be much appreciated.

Also, this approach doesn't exactly force the user to enter, eg, `op1 and op2` in case his `mode=m1`. If it is possible to do something like this as well, it would be bonus benefits for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your program is handling multiple different tasks. The way to support this is to split up your parser into [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands):

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Demo")
parser.add_argument("--foo", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--bar", required=True)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='mode', required=True)

m1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('m1', help='mode 1')
m1_parser.add_argument("--op1", required=True)
m1_parser.add_argument("--op2", required=True)
m1_parser.add_argument("--op3")
m1_parser.add_argument("--op4")
m1_parser.add_argument("--op5")

m2_parser = subparsers.add_parser('m2', help='mode 2')
m2_parser.add_argument("--op1")
m2_parser.add_argument("--op2")
m2_parser.add_argument("--op3", required=True)
m2_parser.add_argument("--op4")
m2_parser.add_argument("--op5")

m3_parser = subparsers.add_parser('m3', help='mode 3')
m3_parser.add_argument("--op1")
m3_parser.add_argument("--op2")
m3_parser.add_argument("--op3")
m3_parser.add_argument("--op4", required=True)
m3_parser.add_argument("--op5", required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.mode == 'm1':
    print(args.op1) # it will always exist
```

Usage:

```
$ python3 args.py m1
usage: args.py m1 [-h] --op1 OP1 --op2 OP2 [--op3 OP3] [--op4 OP4] [--op5 OP5]
args.py m1: error: the following arguments are required: --op1, --op2
```

While this seems repetitive, you now have the option of giving better names to the various options that are specific to the sub-commands.

Comment: Here, `m1` seems to be common `args` argument and not a keyed argument  which is given by argparse. Is it possible to have something like: `python3 args.py --mode m1` to be read by subparsers?

Comment: I added a way to check for the specific mode selected. Does that answer your question? You could add `required=True` to `add_subparsers()` as well to ensure the mode exists.

Comment: But how do I add `foo` and `bar` for this script, my mandatory params (which I need to provide along with `mode`)?

Comment: They can be added to the main parser, just as you did before. I extended my answer.

Comment: I played around with your answer and it basically solves my use case. Much appreciated. However, for my exact use case, can you edit your answer further to add `required=True` in `subparser.add_parse` line as well --> `subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='mode', required=True)`

Comment: @vish4071 done!